# Issues with Heroes Tour Pt5

Tags: angular

After getting to the dashboard part in Routing, everything stopped displaying on localhost. I've tried looking for other answers but can not figure it out. I even copy/pasted the code from the link that says "you should be here" and it still didn't work. These are the error messages I'm seeing in the browser along with my folder structure. I can provide code if needed, but I figured it would be useless since using the exact code from the tutorial didn't seem to work either.

[Browser Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fQ4d.png)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <nav>
            <a routerLink = "/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
            <a routerLink="/heroes">Heroes</a>
        </nav>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
})

export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Tour of Heroes';
}
```

This is app.module.ts.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail.component';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes.component';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
    HeroesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'heroes',
        component: HeroesComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [HeroService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: This [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial)?

Comment: Yes sir. Everything worked fine up until Routing and now nothing works. Continuing through to see if it gets resolved down the road, but it doesn't feel right when they say "it should now look like this" but I still get nothing.

Comment: We need to see your code.. Please add the relevant code like your `my-app` component, your module that imports it and where you use it.

Comment: Well, the only thing that uses 'my-app' is the app.component.ts page. Even then, I'm still unclear as to what it does. Adding to my original post.